# Searchbar didn't worked properly in the draggablescrollablesheet (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I'm a Flutter newbie. I had a trouble with my own searchbar in the draggable bottom sheet. I created a draggable bottom sheet to search for information when clicking to the search field from the main screen. I added a searchbar and a listview in the sheet but the searchbar did not work properly. It could not instantly filter out the data, it just showed the results when closing the keyboard. Anyone helps me please.

```
class AddPersonalInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  final String mail, password;
  const AddPersonalInfo({Key? key, required this.mail, required this.password})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddPersonalInfoState createState() => _AddPersonalInfoState();
}

class _AddPersonalInfoState extends State<AddPersonalInfo> {
  TextEditingController _search = TextEditingController();

  List<City> cites = [
    City(id: 1, code: "HN", name: "Ha Noi"),
    City(id: 2, code: "HCM", name: "Ho CHi Minh"),
    City(id: 3, code: "DN", name: "Da Nang"),
    City(id: 4, code: "HP", name: "Hai Phong"),
    City(id: 5, code: "CT", name: "Can Tho"),
    City(id: 6, code: "DNN", name: "Dong Nai"),
    City(id: 7, code: "KH", name: "Khanh Hoa"),
    City(id: 8, code: "PY", name: "Phu Yen"),
    City(id: 9, code: "NT", name: "Nha Trang"),
    City(id: 10, code: "VL", name: "Vinh Long"),
    City(id: 11, code: "HD", name: "Hai Duong"),
    City(id: 12, code: "BD", name: "Binh Duong")
  ];

  City? selected;

  List<City> foundCity = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    setState(() {
      foundCity = cites;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    Orientation orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.maxWidth <= screenSize.width &&
                orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30 * screenScale(context), 0,
                      30 * screenScale(context), 0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Stack(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                bottom: 20 * screenScale(context)),
                            child: introText("Create account", context),
                          ),
                          backBtn(context),
                        ],
                      ),
                      mainText(
                          "Let's create an account to grab all latest gadgets and enjoy the best experiences.",
                          context),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [_fnameField(), _lnameField()],
                      ),
                      _phoneField(),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => showModalBottomSheet(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          isScrollControlled: true,
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) => buildSheet(),
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 50,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 7),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              selected == null
                                  ? Text("Select city",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          color: Colors.grey.shade700))
                                  : Text("${selected!.name}",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black)),
                              Icon(Ionicons.chevron_down_outline, size: 24)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30 * screenScale(context), 0,
                      30 * screenScale(context), 0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildSheet() {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
      child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize: 0.9,
        builder: (_, controller) => Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
              top: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Divider(
                thickness: 4,
                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                endIndent: 170,
                indent: 170,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, top: 5),
                child: Text("Select city",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: _search,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16 * fontScale(context)),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.circular(7 * screenScale(context))),
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(top: 10 * screenScale(context)),
                    hintText: 'Search',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Ionicons.search_outline),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      foundCity = cites
                          .where(
                              (city) => city.name.toLowerCase().contains(value))
                          .toList();
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: foundCity.length > 0
                    ? ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: foundCity.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final city = foundCity[index];
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(city.name),
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              setState(() {
                                selected = city;
                              });
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      )
                    : Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                        child: Text(
                          "No data.",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I checked you code, and it seems you missed a small issue, when you're creating a showModalBottomSheet, it's no longer part of your stateful widget

I've adjusted the code so that it works now:

```
 Widget buildSheet(BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, setState) {
      return GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
        child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
          initialChildSize: 0.9,
          builder: (_, controller) => Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                top: Radius.circular(20),
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Divider(
                  thickness: 4,
                  color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                  endIndent: 170,
                  indent: 170,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, top: 5),
                  child: Text("Select city",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _search,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                      hintText: 'Search',
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        foundCity = cites
                            .where((city) =>
                                city.name!.toLowerCase().contains(value))
                            .toList();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: foundCity.isNotEmpty
                      ? ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: foundCity.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final city = foundCity[index];
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(city.name!),
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                setState(() {
                                  selected = city;
                                });
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        )
                      : Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                          child: Text(
                            "No data.",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                          ),
                        ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: but there is another issue, i can't choose the city without searching like before, i just can select when searching something or the keyboard is openning. Hope you fix it.

Comment: Ok I'm not sure if this is the right answer but here what you can do, add a FocusNode controller for your TextFormField, and call it (_focus.requestFocus()) before you build your list. This will activate the state.

Comment: Thank you very much @WBG. I've already fixed it, just add statement "this.setState((){})" to call the parent screen's state.